# AWS Lambda function works fine when invoked manually, but not through endpoint

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have a Lambda function, attached to an API Gateway endpoint, that lists the items under an ID in DynamoDB.

I've built my function using the Serverless Framework. When I invoke the function locally (`serverless invoke local ...`) it works fine. When I test it manually on the AWS Lambda console, it works fine, but when I call it from the API Gateway, it doesn't work.

It's configured to use this payload: (What I've used for testing)

```
{
    "requestContext": {
        "identity": {
            "cognitoIdentityId": "468648c5-b135-4075-910a-8a648d66e67d"
        }
   }
}
```

In my app, I use the `aws-amplify` package. This is how I call the endpoint:

```
data = await API.get('endpoint-name', '/endpoint', {
    body: {
        requestContext: {
            cognitoIdentityId: '468648c5-b135-4075-910a-8a648d66e67d'
        }
    }
});
```

Here, I get a `403` error. If I call it without the extra data, i.e:

```
data = await API.get('endpoint-name', '/endpoint');
```

I get an empty list `[ ]`, but no error. Does `aws-amplify` automatically populate the `cognitoIdentityId` field? I'm following the [serverless-stack](http://serverless-stack.com/) tutorial, and they kinda gloss over this.

I also have `CloudWatch` set up, and I cannot see anything funky there. Any ideas on how to fix / debug this issue?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ah - I think I solved it!

I configured my endpoint to take parameters from the body of a `GET` request, however (I think) either `aws-amplify` or the `API Gateway` doesn't support a request body when performing a `GET`. I noticed this by manually testing the `API Gateway` (Which I hadn't done before), and it stated `Request Body is not supported for GET methods`.

So I think I'll have to pass my parameters in the URL itself.

Comment: I think the `GET` method in HTTP does not include a body by definition.